# Metric in which consecutive primes have equivalent gaps?

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, prime-numbers, infinite-product, natural-numbers

I thought that maybe the following product could be a good start to look for a metric in which consecutive primes are the same distance apart.

$$\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^\infty \big(p_k-1\big)^k}$$ where the product runs over the primes.

> How do you construct a metric in which the primes are evenly spaced (1 unit). For example the natural numbers from one to the next always differ by exactly one unit. That is the gaps, are exactly $1$ unit from 2 to 3, from 3 to 4, from 4 to 5 and so on. How do you do this for the primes?

So the metric should be $d(p_n,p_{n+1})=1.$ Someone suggested using the discrete metric, in which case *any* two numbers would have distance equal to $1$ unit.

Comment: Your definition of $J(k)$ - the notation makes it seem like it depends on $k$, and yet $k$ is the index of the product. The product is clearly infinite anyway. Anyway, what does this product have to do with the main question?

Comment: @Wojowu that's a good point, I think the product needs to stand alone. My initial thought was that the product would help define a helpful metric

Comment: I do not think it will be helpful in any way, in part because it's infinite.

Comment: Oh wait I meant to write the reciprocal... sorry

Comment: -1. The question is trivial because there are  lot of metrics $d$ on $\Bbb N$ such that $d(p_n,p_{n+1})=1$ for each $n$. For instance,  keeping $d(p_n,p_{n+1})=d(p_{n+1}, p_n)=1$ for each $n$, we can put $d(r,s)=d(s,r)$ be any number beetween $1$ and $2$ for the remaining pairs $r,s$ of natural numbers. I think to make the question non-trivial, on $d$ should be imposed rather strong restrictions.

Comment: what kind of restrictions? @AlexRavsky

Comment: This is your question and you decide, what your need. For instance, why a trivial mertic $d(x,y)=1$, if $x=y$, and  $d(x,x)=0$ for each natural $x$ and $y$ doesn't fit your purposes.

Comment: A trivial metric is not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define the function
$\alpha:\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$ via
$$
\alpha(k) = 
n + \frac{k-p_n}{p_{n+1}-p_n},
$$
where $n$ is such that $p_n\leq k < p_{n+1}$,
with the exception $\alpha(1)=0$.

Note that this function
is injective and satisifes $\alpha(p_n)=n$.

We then define our metric on $\Bbb N$ via
$$
d(k,m):= |\alpha(k)-\alpha(m)|.
$$
Using that $\alpha$ is injective and that $|\cdot|$ is a metric on $\Bbb R$,
one can show that $d$ is indeed a metric on $\Bbb N$.

Moreover, we also have
$$d(p_n,p_{n+1})=|\alpha(p_n)-\alpha(p_{n+1})| = |n-(n+1)|=1,$$
which satisfies your desired property.